# How do I Terminate a function after T seconds OR after a certain condition is met. The function deals with taking input

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

I would like to briefly explain to you the problem I'm facing with a small example.

My C++ program has a function `void X()` which is called from `int main()`.

What `void x()` does is, it takes five strings as input and stores them somewhere (as shown below).

```
vector <string> input;
bool finished_taking_five_inputs = false;

void X() {
    string in;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> in;
        input.push_back(in);
    }
    finished_taking_five_inputs = true;
}
```

This `void X()` function is supposed to run for exactly `T` seconds (**Even if the program is waiting for input**).

***Example 1:***
*If `T = 40 secs`, and currently the time elapsed is `39` seconds, and even if the user is typing some input. The function `X()` should terminate on 40th second. It is basically like an exam timer.*

***Example 2:***
*If `T = 40 secs`, and currently the time elapsed is `20` seconds, and user has entered all the five strings, then the `X()` should be terminated*

Finally, at the end of `main()`, I print all the strings (which may or may not be five). Like below:

```
int main() {
    X();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        cout << input[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**What I did?**

I have created a `std::thread` named `t1` which runs function `X()`:

```
int main() {
    int RUNNING_TIME = 40;
    thread t1(X);

    /* t1 starts executing independently from the calling thread main */
    t1.detach();

    /* Main thread sleeps for RUNNING_TIME seconds */
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(RUNNING_TIME));

    /* Once the RUNNING_TIME is over, it prints the input */
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << input[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***My problem***

I was able to achieve the timer functionality, but if the user finishes the input within `T`seconds, my code still waits for `T` seconds to pass.

How do I run `thread t1` for `T` seconds ***OR*** until a specific condition is met? Here the condition is when the boolean variable becomes true `finished_taking_five_inputs = true;` in function `X()`.

Can someone please help me how to achieve this functionality with C++ features? I'm quite a novice in thread concepts.

Comment: Standard C++ does not provide what you want.  You'll need to use a library like **ncurses** or your operating system's API.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: @SamuelÅslund Yes, I did see it. But still figuring out how to add a condition variable that notifies the main thread and halts the `sleep_for()`

Comment: In standard C++, there is no way to break a blocked I/O operation, like reading input from `cin`. Once the code reaches `cin >> in`, it is blocked until input is entered, no timer can change that. So, you need to instead use OS-specific I/O routines that support timeouts, or use a wrapper library, like Eljay suggested.

Comment: You have the "finished_taking_five_inputs " ?